# SSRS Include a sub report into a main report

Tags: reporting-services

I have a Main report and a sub report that have a common id between them and different data sets .

Steps I used but not able to see the preview of the report

1) Drag the sub report into main report.Right click on sub report properties and select the sub report and then in parameters I am giving the parameter I used for the sub report on the left side and a value from the main report data set, but the page keeps on loading and does not lead to anything

Can someone tell me how to solve it

Comment: What does "page keeps on loading and does not lead to anything" mean?

Comment: If I just have one record then the page will load if not the page does not load forever .How do I optimize this problem.